# Use a GraphQL API in another GraphQL API

Tags: javascript, java, backend, graphql

I have two GraphQL schemas. One is written in Javascript and the other is written in Java.

Is there any way for me to combine the two into a single GraphQL implementation.

For example:

GraphQL Server A can query the following:

```
{
    cats
}
```

GraphQL Server B can query the following:

```
{
    dogs
}
```

I want my GraphQL Server to be able to query by somehow combining the two together

```
{
    cats
    dogs
}
```

I want to know if there is something that exists that does this already or if I have to do it myself. If I have to do it myself where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, the term for it that the community has settled on is "schema stitching"

1. Apollo [graphql-tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html) has a solution <-- I would start with this one
2. [These guys](https://www.aeb.com/intl/index.php) have [a solution](https://github.com/aeb-labs/graphql-weaver)
3. And I created [a simple solution](https://github.com/brysgo/graphql-gateway) that I would **not** recommend using unless you have a really strong opinion and are willing to contribute to supporting it if I decided not to.